# Split large XML files into smaller pieces in php

Tags: php, xml

How can i split a large xml file into smaller ones  more exactely i want one xml file for each node and the name of the xml file to be given by a child fron node.

XML file has the below structure

```
<Products>
  <Products>
    <ID>ID</ID>
    <Name>Product_Name</Name>
    <Qty>qty</Qty>
    <Brand>Brand</Brand>
     ......
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <ID>ID</ID>
    <Name>Product_Name</Name>
    <Qty>qty</Qty>
    <Brand>Brand</Brand>
     ......
  </Product>
  <Product>
   ........
  </Product>
</Products>
```

I have searched over the internet and i have found only c# solutions and i dont know c#

So i need to have one XML file for each product and the name of the xml file is given by the value from `<ID></ID>`

Comment: would you consider a java based answer acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

You should do something with DomDocument and [XPath](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.domxpath.php)
Try with: **//Product[./ID/text()="ID2"]** or just **//Product**

Answer (score 0):

You might use XSL(T) for that (or maybe not, depending on the server configuration).
The current version of libxslt is still xsl 1.0 and doesn't support [`xsl:result-document`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-result-document).
But it supports the [`exsl:document`](http://exslt.org/exsl/elements/document/) extension which serves pretty much the same purpose.

```
<?php
$xsl = new XSLTProcessor;
$xsl->setSecurityPrefs(
    $xsl->getSecurityPrefs() ^ XSL_SECPREF_WRITE_FILE
);


$xsl->importStylesheet( doc(style()) );
$doc = doc( data() );

$xsl->transformToXML($doc);

function doc($xml) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    $doc->loadxml($xml);
    return $doc;
}

function style() {
    return <<< eox
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
                extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="Products/Product">
        <exsl:document href="Product{ID}.xml" method="html">
            <Product>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </Product>
        </exsl:document>
        </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
eox;
}

function data() {
    return <<< eox
<Products>
    <Product>
        <ID>ID1</ID>
        <Name>Product_Name1</Name>
        <Qty>qty1</Qty>
        <Brand>Brand1</Brand>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <ID>ID2</ID>
        <Name>Product_Name2</Name>
        <Qty>qty2</Qty>
        <Brand>Brand2</Brand>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <ID>ID3</ID>
        <Name>Product_Name3</Name>
        <Qty>qty3</Qty>
        <Brand>Brand3</Brand>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <ID>ID4</ID>
        <Name>Product_Name4</Name>
        <Qty>qty4</Qty>
        <Brand>Brand4</Brand>
    </Product>
</Products>
eox;
}
```

creates on my machine four files( ProductID1.xml ... ProductID4.xml ), each containing the data of one Product element.
[XsltProcessor::setSecurityPrefs](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.setsecurityprefs.php) is relatively new. Your script should check whether the xsl instance has such a method and if not instead use `ini_set('xsl.security_prefs'...)` to disable the "write protection". Otherwise instead of the output you might get a bunch of

```
Warning: XSLTProcessor::transformToXml(): File write for ProductID1.xml refused in ...test.php on line ...
```

warning/errors.
And maybe instead of the `<Product><xsl:apply-templates />` construct `<xsl:copy-of select="."/>` is more suited.